# Phobos library function for converting a uint to binary string

Tags: d, phobos

Is there a Phobos function that converts an unsigned integer to a binary string? I've searched, but couldn't find one - just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel by writing my own.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by converting an integer to a binary string. Are you looking to convert `22` to `"22"`, or do you mean some other type of conversion?

Comment: I'm looking to convert ``13`` to ``"1101"``, actually.

Comment: So, you want to convert an integer to a base 2 value as a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std.conv.to`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#.to) is the swiss army knife of conversion functions, and it supports converting to and from different bases. So, if you want to convert 13 to its base 2 value as a string - `"1101"` - then you'd do

```
auto str = to!string(13, 2);
assert(str == "1101");
```

and to convert a string containing a base 2 integer to an integer, just do the reverse

```
auto i = to!int("1101", 2);
assert(i == 13);
```

[`std.conv.parse`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html#.parse) has similar functionality, but it's for parsing a value from the beginning of a string (with the idea of parsing out several whitespace-separated values from the string) rather than converting the entire string at once. It also doesn't work to construct a string from a value, just a value from a string.